# O que fazer quando uma pergunta é posta em suspensão por usuários que não possuem experiência com o contexto?

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento, comunidade

Algum tempo atrás fiz uma pergunta relacionada a virtualização de ambiente de desenvolvimento, [Como configurar o Netbeans para trabalhar com o PHPUnit em ambiente virtualizado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3368/netbeans-virtualbox-phpunit).

A pergunta é um problema que muitos que adotam a prática têm, porem vários usuários responderam com opiniões sobre virtualizar ou não, e marcaram a pergunta como irrelevante ou mal escrita.

Sinto que a pergunta foi avaliada levando em consideração a opinião, sendo que se tratava de um assunto bem específico, não tendo motivo de discutir se é uma boa prática ou não.

Fiz a mesma pergunta em outras comunidades do PHP e a abertura para tentar resolver o problema foi muito maior, pois quem faz uso da prática, se sentiu interessado, e quem não conhecia buscou conhecer.

Sinalizar para suspender uma pergunta por questão de opinião não deveria ser válido. Creio que o processo de suspender uma pergunta deveria ser mais criterioso, e sugiro que quem sinalizar uma pergunta sem um bom fundamento, poderia ter algum tipo de punição, evitando que o ato de sinalizar seja banalizado e não acabe atrapalhando a comunidade.

Comment: Complementando as duas excelentes respostas: você já pensou que se você não consegue melhorar o que está lá, talvez não esteja claro para você qual é o problema? Estamos aqui para tentar ajudá-lo mas precisamos seguir a filosofia do site. É ela que diferencia o SO ou o SOpt de todos os outros sites. Ele tem vantagens e desvantagens. Uma das vantagens é que o conteúdo é mais claro, fácil de achar e ajuda outras pessoas além do autor da pergunta. Ao mesmo que tempo que exige-se que todos sejam mais claros, organizados e pensar sempre que  a solução apresentada deve ser útil para outras pessoas.

Comment: Eu não entendo como não ser claro, eu quero configurar o Netbeans para executar o PHP Unit que está instalado em uma maquina virtual. Apenas isso, nada mirabolante. Eu concordo com tudo o que responderam, mas eu coloquei uma pergunta simples e direta e me pediram pra detalhar tanto que parece que estou configurando a rede da NASA

Comment: @marcusagm Essa quantidade de detalhes serve pra facilitar o trabalho das pessoas que vão te ajudar. Uma pergunta aqui é um pedido de ajuda para milhares de desconhecidos, que não vão poder sentar uma tarde toda e debugar com você, então quanto mais claro você deixar o problema (mensagens de erro, resultado esperado, etc) melhor alguém vai poder te ajudar.

Comment: Acho que a comunidade aqui ainda vai amadurecer e melhorar. É muito nova ainda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Sinto que a pergunta foi avaliada levando em consideração a opinião, sendo que se tratava de um assunto bem específico [...] e marcaram a pergunta como irrelevante ou mal escrita.

Bom, realmente não tenho experiência com Vagrant e testes em VMs, mas mesmo assim consigo identificar que faltam alguns dados essenciais na sua pergunta. A versão do Netbeans, por exemplo. Você mostrou seus resultados de pesquisa, mas sinto que faltou indicar o que você realmente tentou e por quais razões não serviu para seu caso de uso, ou em qual parte do tutorial você ficou preso.

Acredito que sem estes dados, a pergunta se torna branda demais (não objetivamente clara) para o site.

> [...] porem vários usuários responderam com opiniões sobre virtualizar ou não [...]

Vale notar que comentários não são respostas. Comentários são apenas "barulho" (embora, algumas vezes, seja possível encontrar uma resposta dentre eles). Comentários servem primeiramente para pedir detalhamento, dar dicas ou opiniões que não solucionam a questão.

> Sinalizar para suspender uma pergunta por questão de opinião não deveria ser válido. Creio que o processo de suspender uma pergunta deveria ser mais criterioso, e sugiro que quem sinalizar uma pergunta sem um bom fundamento, poderia ter algum tipo de punição, evitando que o ato de sinalizar seja banalizado e não acabe atrapalhando a comunidade.

Meus pensamentos:

- Sites do Stack Exchange são planejados para serem "auto-sustentáveis", ou mais especificamente, moderados pela própria comunidade. Seria insustentável pedir que moderadores revisassem todas suspensões, mas você pode certamente sinalizar caso haja algum abuso.
- Votar para suspender é um privilégio dado a usuários mais experientes (a reputação necessária deve aumentar após o site sair do beta). São necessários **5 votos** destes usuários mais experientes para suspender uma questão, logo suspensões indevidas são um tanto raras.
- Existe o sistema de re-abertura para casos em que a questão tenha sido melhorada após a sua suspensão, ou tenha sido suspensa erroneamente.
- Sinalizações são um direito de todos usuários, e sinalizações indevidas já acarretam perda do peso de sinalizações futuras. Vale notar que sinalizações indevidas não tem efeito nenhum sobre sua questão, elas são simplesmente dispensadas por moderadores e usuários com direito de votar para suspender.

Answer (score 9):

A pergunta só tem uma resposta, que parece *tentar* responder ao que você perguntou. O resto são comentários. Ela foi marcada como "não é claro o que você está perguntado". Isso é usado para indicar que as pessoas não estão entendendo a pergunta, e desejam mais esclarecimentos do autor. Esse motivo de suspensão/fechamento não carrega juízo de valor sobre relevância.

A suspensão de uma pergunta não é o fim da linha para ela. Longe disso. O objetivo é que os problemas sejam resolvidos para que ela seja reaberta. Se isso não ocorrer rapidamente, ela é rotulada como "fechada", mas continua sendo passível de reabertura a qualquer momento. Você editou sua pergunta e me parece que é possível respondê-la na forma atual. Por isso, dei um voto para reabri-la, e fiz mais algumas edições tentando deixá-la ainda mais clara. E acho que ainda tem espaço para você complementar com informações adicionais.

---

Quanto aos demais pontos que você menciona, eu tenho algumas discordâncias.

> Sinto que a pergunta foi avaliada levando em consideração a opinião, sendo que se tratava de um assunto bem específico, não tendo motivo de discutir se é uma boa prática ou não.

Eu não vi ninguém discutindo se é uma boa prática ou não. Talvez tenha havido comentários excluídos (houve?). Nada ali me dá a entender que os votos para fechar foram baseados nesse tipo de julgamento.

> Fiz a mesma pergunta em outras comunidades do PHP e a abertura para tentar resolver o problema foi muito maior

Eu entendo que a maneira como este site funciona às vezes possa parecer hostil. Mas o objetivo dele é um pouco diferente do dos outros. Não queremos somente responder à *sua* pergunta, queremos gerar conteúdo que seja útil para um número maior de pessoas. Uma pergunta que não estiver clara não ajuda, pois as pessoas precisam *pressupor* as informações que faltam para conseguir responder. O resultado é uma série de respostas conflitantes e mancas. Isso também não ajuda. Por isso existe a ferramenta de suspender/fechar. O objetivo principal é tentar chamar a atenção (do autor e da comunidade) para o fato de que a pergunta precisa ser melhorada, e não varrê-la do mapa (isso seria *exclusão*, não fechamento).

> Sinalizar para suspender uma pergunta por questão de opinião não deveria ser válido. Creio que o processo de suspender uma pergunta deveria ser mais criterioso, e sugiro que quem sinalizar uma pergunta sem um bom fundamento, poderia ter algum tipo de punição, evitando que o ato de sinalizar seja banalizado e não acabe atrapalhando a comunidade.

Não acho que votar/sinalizar para fechar esteja banalizado aqui. São necessários 5 usuários para suspender uma pergunta. E o fechamento é sempre reversível. Além disso, o site ainda é muito novo e a comunidade está se formando e se ajustando às ferramentas. Muitos vêm do SO em inglês, que tem regras muito mais rígidas. Mesmo assim, não enxergo uma situação de descontrole em que perguntas são fechadas sem motivos. Se um dia chegarmos a isso, aí sim podemos considerar algum tipo de punição, mas não é nem de longe o caso neste momento.

Comment: Alguns comentários sugeriram que a máquina virtual não é o melhor caminho mas, como você falou, os comentários e os votos para fechar não possuem relação uns com os outros.